# How to reorder a python list backwards starting with the 0th element?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to go through a list in reverse order, starting with the -0 indexed item (which is also the 0th item), rather than the -1 indexed item, so that I'll now have the new list to use.  I've come up with two ways to do this, but neither seems both concise and clear.

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print(a_list[:1] + a_list[:0:-1])    # take two slices of the list and add them
# [1, 5, 4, 3, 2]

list_range = range(-len(a_list)+1,1)[::-1]    # create an appropriate new index range mapping
print([a_list[i] for i in list_range])        # list comprehension on the new range mapping
# [1, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Is there a way in python 3 to use slicing or another method to achieve this more simply?

Comment: What do you mean by `-0th is also 0th` element?

Comment: @Sukumar Rdjf `a_list[0] == a_list[-0]`

Comment: what is your expected output? if you want to reverse the list you can do `a_list[::-1]`

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar I don't want to do a simple reverse of the list starting on the last item. the expected output is given by the working code examples, and is included in the comments after each print

Answer (score 5):

If you are up for a programming golf:

```
>>> a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [a_list[-i] for i in range(len(a_list))]
[1, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your first suggestion is the cleanest way of doing this. If you're really optimizing for character count, you can remove two characters from the first slice:

```
print(a_list[:1] + a_list[:0:-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Shift everything left by one and reverse.

```
my_list.append(my_list.pop(0))
print my_list[::-1]
```

Comment: This looks to be the fastest for cases where I don't need to preserve the original list, which is a good alternative to have on hand. +1